# iterating over cases in c++ switch statement?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in the c++ world and I'm currently writing a program, which would execute many variations of the same command. I figured I could do this with the Switch statement, but I can't get it to work. So to be clear, I want my program to execute every case in switch statement, I tried something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int x(0);

while(x<4){
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:(some code);
        case 2:(some code);
        case 3:(some code);
    }
  }
}
```

Is this even possible? Thank you.

Comment: Why not try it - you never know it may work!

Comment: That right there should work.

Comment: first initialize `x` correctly and then move

Comment: Also note, you're not changing `x` inside your loop, unless `some code` does.

Comment: @rock321987 - it is initialised correctly. Admittedly not orthodox

Comment: the initialization type is new to me..my bad i didn't knew it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You've accidentally written an infinite loop because you're not incrementing `x`, which you probably want to do after the switch.

But if you just want to run those 3 blocks of code in that order, why not just have those 3 blocks of code in that order? You gain absolutely nothing by wrapping them up in the loop and the switch. Let's say you wrote 3 functions. This block of code:

```
while(x<4){
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
           f1();
           break;
        case 2:
           f2();
           break;
        case 3:
           f3();
           break;
    }
    x++;
  }
```

is exactly the same as:

```
   f1();
   f2();
   f3();
```

If there is a lot of similarity between the stuff you would put in each of these 3 functions, perhaps write one function and call it 3 times, with slightly different parameters.

Comment: Thanks, will do that with functions!

Answer (score -1):

It is because you're not incrementing your x value after the switch block. therefore your program is trapped into an infinite while loop.